# Upgrading highcharts from 8.0.4 to 9.0.1 throws error TypeError: e.remove is not a function

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I had upgraded highcharts from 8.0.4 to 9.0.1 to exploit the floating ability of range selector buttons and because of this https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14436. Since then I get the following error on code deploy.

```
TypeError: e.remove is not a function
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on the online editor?

Comment: I am not quite able to reproduce it but I get this error on resize of the browser any leads will be great!

Comment: @Deflin it's hard to say more without seeing the code

Comment: @SebastianWędzel agree! I boiled down the issue to this. The code used to break for pane property of responsive rules for the solid gauge chart. Removing only the pane property from responsive rules fixed this issue. But I checked on the fiddle of other users they do have pane property and the code dint break. Any insights?

Comment: Once again, without the demo, I cannot say more...